# Copy, rename and move a document

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google Doc based on form data.  I have done this with other forms that take the Doc and save them as PDFs.  With this script, I have been able to create new docs and rename the file, but I need to move them to a different folder.  The code I used for doing this with PDFs works (at the very bottom) without problems but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have not had any luck searching for working solutions online either.

```
var TEMPLATE_ID = 'template id number'; 
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder ID number');

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Goal Tracking"),
activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
copyId = copyFile.getId(),
copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(),
numberOfColumns = sheet.getLastColumn(),
activeRowIndex = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
columnIndex = 0,

fileName = "Goals " + activeRow[0][2] + ' ' + activeRow[0][3]+'_'+activeRow[0][5]; 

//Get information from form and set as variables.  

var lastName = e.values[2];
var firstName = e.values[3];
var programCode = e.values[4];
var goal1 = e.values[6];
var goal2 = e.values[7];
var goal3 = e.values[8];

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template

copyBody.replaceText('%First Name%', firstName);
copyBody.replaceText('%Last Name%', lastName);
copyBody.replaceText('%Program Code%', programCode);
copyBody.replaceText('%Goal Statement 1%', goal1);
copyBody.replaceText('%Goal Statement 2%', goal2);
copyBody.replaceText('%Goal Statement 3%', goal3);  

 // Save and close the temporary document

 copyDoc.saveAndClose();
 copyDoc.setName(fileName);
```

(continuing on)
Here is where the problem is

```
 folder.addFile(newFile);
  }
```

I do get an error in the execution transcript but I don't understand why I am getting it: 'Cannot find method addFile(Document)."   I also tried to use:

```
    copyDoc.makeCopy(fileName, folder).getId;
```

to set a file name and folder location but it also failed.

For what its worth, here is what I have used to create a PDF that does work in this script.

```
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

var  pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs("application/pdf"));
var  pdfFile2 = pdfFile.setName(fileName); 

 folder.addFile(pdfFile2); 
    copyFile.setTrashed(true);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Use a `Logger.log('folder: ' + folder);` statement right before the `folder.addFile(newFile);` statement.  In the Logs, it should show **folder: folder**  If the folder is null or undefined, that would cause the error.  The only other possibility is that there is something wrong with the `newFile` parameter.  I don't see where `newFile` is being set.

Comment: Logger.log doesn't help, except it hows the correct folder in the log/transcript, so I assume it must be newFile parameter you mentioned.  I did try to set the newFile parameter by creating:  `var newFile = copyDoc.setName(fileName);`  It does set the name but doesn't move the file to a different folder.  The exeution transcript still says `Cannot find method addFile (document)`

Comment: I figured it out.  Had to change `copyDoc.setName(fileName)`  to `copyFile.setName(fileName)`.  I can't say I fully understand why that is except I am a newbee anyway.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Always look at the return types returned from a method.  The `setName()` method of the document Class returns a document, not a file.  [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setnamename)   The `setName()` method of the DriveApp class returns a file.

Answer (score 3):

This code moves the folder, and rename the file.

```
function myFunction() {
  var dstFolderId = "0B1ECfqTCcLE8c09YZUtqTkVwU3c";

  var targetFileId = "0B1ECfqTCcLE8SS1PRnJ1cVgxVlk";
  var targetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(targetFileId);

  var newFileName = "HelloWorld.pdf";

  // Remove current parent folders
  var parentFolders = targetFile.getParents();
  while(parentFolders.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parentFolders.next();
    parent.removeFile(targetFile);
  }

  // Add the target file into the new folder
  var dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId);
  dstFolder.addFile(targetFile);

  // Rename if you want.
  targetFile.setName(newFileName);
}
```