# Collect receipt data from users with Google Form and save in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, google-sheets

I would like to create a script to receive expense receipts in a Google drive, and log details provided by a Google Form (date, vendor, amount, and picture of the receipt...)

I've tried to replicate the script and html from [How do I rename files uploaded to an apps script web app form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450137/how-do-i-rename-files-uploaded-to-an-apps-script-web-app-form), and end up with error 400 with no details...

Also tried to merge Amit Agarwal's script

https://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/

with https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server

Second example logs entries into google sheets, but also sends email : Perfect! Amit's example allows to create named folders and I can rename the file with some additionnal code, love it!

But in my try to merge both, I end up with two buttons at the bottom of the form... one sends the rows, the other sends the file! :D

Here's my actual script.gs

```
    // if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
//var TO_ADDRESS = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
// uses an array of keys if provided or the object to determine field order

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').setTitle("envoyez vos pièces jointes");
}


// this is from Amit Agarwal's example

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, prenom, nom) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Justificatifs reçus";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }


    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
        file = folder.createFolder([prenom, nom].join(" ")).createFile(blob);

       //this is an addition i've made to rename the files upon submission, used to work in previous tries, but now gives "null null.pdf'
       //var newFileName = [prenom +'_'+ nom +".pdf"];
       //file.setName(newFileName); 



    return "OK";

  } catch (f) {
    return f.toString();
  }

}

// Here stops Amit Agarwal's script, below is  the following of 
//https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server

function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  if (!order) {
    order = Object.keys(obj);
  }


  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

// sanitize content from the user - trust no one 
// ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)
function sanitizeInput(rawInput) {
   var placeholder = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(" ");
   placeholder.appendUntrusted(rawInput);

   return placeholder.getContent();
 }

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }

    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;

    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // hold off up to 30 sec to avoid concurrent writing

  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it

    // select the 'responses' sheet by default
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var oldHeader = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var newHeader = oldHeader.slice();
    var fieldsFromForm = getDataColumns(e.parameters);
    var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp

    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);

      // mark as stored by removing from form fields
      var formIndex = fieldsFromForm.indexOf(field);
      if (formIndex > -1) {
        fieldsFromForm.splice(formIndex, 1);
      }
    }

    // set any new fields in our form
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsFromForm.length; i++) {
      var field = fieldsFromForm[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      newHeader.push(field);
    }

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // update header row with any new data
    if (newHeader.length > oldHeader.length) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, newHeader.length).setValues([newHeader]);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return;
  }

}

function getDataColumns(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(function(column) {
    return !(column === 'formDataNameOrder' || column === 'formGoogleSheetName' || column === 'formGoogleSendEmail' || column === 'honeypot');
  });
}

function getFieldFromData(field, data) {
  var values = data[field] || '';
  var output = values.join ? values.join(', ') : values;
  return output;
}
```

And here's the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Envoyez vos justificatifs</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style>
      .disclaimer{width: 480px; color:#646464;margin:20px auto;padding:0 16px;text-align:center;font:400 12px Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif}.disclaimer a{color:#009688}#credit{display:none}
    </style>
  </head>



<!-- START HERE -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <!-- Style The Contact Form How Ever You Prefer -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <form class="gform pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST" data-email="example@email.net"
  action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzSlohhLp27NcnG8lBt13GUm4PblUMTL9uU1CTgcOBohz1iH0k/exec"
  id="form" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
   <div id="forminner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Envoyez vos justificatifs</h5>
            <p class="disclaimer">This <a href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/">File Upload Form</a> (<a href="https://youtu.be/C_YBBupebvE">tutorial</a>) is powered by <a href="https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files" target="_blank">Google Scripts</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>


<fieldset class="pure-group">
        <legend><H5>Vous êtes</H5></legend>
        <input id="radio-group--madame" type="radio" name="radio-group" value="madame"> <label for="radio-group--madame">Madame</label>
        <input id="radio-group--monsieur" type="radio" name="radio-group" value="monsieur"> <label for="radio-group--monsieur">Monsieur</label>
              </fieldset>


<div class="form-elements">
      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="firstname">Votre prénom</label>
        <input id="firstname" name="Prénom" placeholder="indiquez votre prénom" />
      </fieldset>

    <div class="form-elements">
      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="name">Votre nom</label>
        <input id="name" name="Nom" placeholder="indiquez votre nom" />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="email"><em>Votre</em> Adresse email</label>
        <input id="email" name="Votre adresse email" type="email" value=""
        required placeholder="Alice@paydesmerv.... ou votre vrai adresse pour recevoir la confirmation"/>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <legend><H5>Votre dépense</H5></legend>
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input id="date" type="date" name="date de la dépense" value="">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="time">Heure de la dépense</label>
        <input id="time" type="time" name="Heure de la dépense" value="">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="menu">Type de dépense</label>
        <select id="menu" name="Type de dépense">
          <option selected="">Je ne sais pas quel type de dépense choisir</option>
          <option>Carburant (essence, diesel, gasoil)</option>
          <option>Location de matériel (voiture, informatique, photocopieur)</option>
          <option>Voyages et déplacements (train, transports, taxi, VTC, péages, parking, avion)</option>
          <option>Frais postaux (La Poste, timbres, colis, lettre recommandée)</option>
          <option>Frais de mission (repas, restaurants)</option>
          <option>Frais de missions (logement, hôtel)</option>
          <option>Divers</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="number">Montant de la dépense en €</label>
        <input id="number" type="number" name="Montant de la dépense" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <textarea id="message" name="Message Facultatif" rows="10"
        placeholder="Vous pouvez apporter des précisions sur la dépense ici..."></textarea>
      </fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group honeypot-field">
        <label for="honeypot">To help avoid spam, utilize a Honeypot technique with a hidden text field; must be empty to submit the form! Otherwise, we assume the user is a spam bot.</label>
        <input id="honeypot" type="text" name="honeypot" value="" />
      </fieldset>


           <legend><H5>Ajoutez le justificatif</H5></legend>
           <p> Pas de remboursement possible sans justificatif</p>

<!-- Here is the issue: code below sends the file to my drive but no new row is added to the spreadsheet. -->

<div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
            <div class="btn">
              <span>Fichier</span>
              <input id="files" type="file" name="Fichier reçu" multiple>
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="choisissez un fichier sur votre ordinateur">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


<!-- code below creates new row with filename but does not upload the file to drive...
exemple from : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file -->


<form action="/action_page.php">
  Select files: <input type="file" name="Fichier reçu"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>




         <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>

    </div>

    <!-- Customise the Thankyou Message People See when they submit the form: -->
    <div class="thankyou_message" style="display:none;">
      <h2><em>Thanks</em> for contacting us!
        We will get back to you soon!</h2>
    </div>

  </form>

  <!-- Submit the Form to Google Using "AJAX" -->
  <script data-cfasync="false" src="form-submission-handler.js"></script>
<!-- END -->


        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id = "progress">
          </div>
        </div>

      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <h5 class="left-align teal-text">File Uploaded</h5>
        <p>Your file has been successfully uploaded.</p>
        <p>The <a href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/">pro version</a> (see <a href="shorturl">demo form</a>) includes a visual drag-n-drop form builder, CAPTCHAs, the form responses are saved in a Google Spreadsheet and respondents can upload multiple files of any size.</p>    
        <p class="center-align"><a  class="btn btn-large" href="https://gum.co/GA14?wanted=true" target="_blank">Upgrade to Pro</a></p>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"  href="shorturl" target="_blank" title="Buy License - File Upload Form"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue"  href="shorturl" target="_blank" title="Video Tutorial"><i class="material-icons">video_library</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green" href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/" target="_blank" title="How to Create File Upload Forms"><i class="material-icons">help</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>

    <script>

      var file, 
          reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.error != null) {
          showError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
          return;
        } else {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
            .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, $('input#nom').val(), $('input#prenom').val());
        }
      };

      function showSuccess(e) {
        if (e === "OK") { 
          $('#forminner').hide();
          $('#success').show();
        } else {
          showError(e);
        }
      }

      function submitForm() {

        var files = $('#files')[0].files;

        if (files.length === 0) {
          showError("Choisissez un fichier a télécharger");
          return;
        }

        file = files[0];

        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
          showError("The file size should be < 5 MB. Please <a href='http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/' target='_blank'>upgrade to premium</a> for receiving larger files in Google Drive");
          return;
        }

        showMessage("Téléchargement du fichier");

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      }

      function showError(e) {
        $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      function showMessage(e) {
        $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
      }


    </script>
```

So, I'd like to have a unique form to send emails, log into sheets and save file in drive.

Additionally, that would be perfect is the file link could appear inside sheets and if the uploaded file could also be sent as attachment with the email.

Thanks a lot for proof reading my codes and putting me on the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

**Collecting Receipt Information**

This function collects Date,Vendor,Amount and Uploads an image. It runs as both a dialog and/or a webapp.  The spreadsheet displays the images url which allows you to hover over in order to get a link to the image which can be view in a default viewer.

This is the form:

[image]
Here's the code:

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Receipt Collection')
    .addItem('Get Receipt', 'showAsDialog')
    .addToUi();
}

function uploadTheForm(theForm) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(theForm));
  var rObj={};
  rObj['vendor']=theForm.vendor;
  rObj['amount']=theForm.amount;
  rObj['date']=theForm.date;
  rObj['notes']=theForm.notes;
  var fileBlob=Utilities.newBlob(theForm.bytes, theForm.mimeType, theForm.filename);
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(receiptImageFolderId);
  rObj['file']=fldr.createFile(fileBlob);
  rObj['filetype']=fileBlob.getContentType(); 
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rObj));
  var cObj=formatFileName(rObj);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(cObj));
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  ss.getSheetByName('Receipt Information').appendRow([cObj.date,cObj.vendor,cObj.amount,cObj.notes,cObj.file.getUrl()]);
  var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />FileName: %s',cObj.file.getName());
  return html;
}

function formatFileName(rObj) {
  if(rObj) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rObj));
    var mA=rObj.date.split('-');
    var name=Utilities.formatString('%s_%s_%s.%s',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(mA[0],mA[1]-1,mA[2]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd"),rObj.vendor,rObj.amount,rObj.filetype.split('/')[1]);
    rObj.file.setName(name);
  }else{
      throw('Invalid or No File in formatFileName() upload.gs');
  }
  return rObj;
}

function doGet() {
  var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('receipts').setTitle('Receipt Information');
  return output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=360, initial-scale=1');
}

function showAsDialog() {
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('receipts');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Receipts')
}
```

receipts.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
          $('#dt').val(rObj.date);
          //$('#vndr').val(rObj.vendor);
          //$('#amt').val(rObj.amount);
          //$('#notes').val(rObj.notes);
        })
        .initForm();
        
      });
      function fileUploadJs(frmData) {
        var amt=$('#amt').val();
        var vndr=$('#vndr').val();
        var img=$('#img').val();
        if(!amt){
          window.alert('No amount provided');
          $('#amt').focus();
          return;
        }
        if(!vndr) {
          window.alert('No vendor provided');
          $('#vndr').focus();
          return;
        }
        if(!img) {
          window.alert('No image chosen');
          $('#img').focus();
        }
        document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
        const file = frmData.receipt.files[0];
        const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = function(e) {
            const obj = {vendor:frmData.elements.vendor.value, date:frmData.elements.date.value, amount: frmData.elements.amount.value, notes: frmData.elements.notes.value, filename: file.name, mimeType:file.type, bytes:[...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]};
            google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=hl;
            })
            .uploadTheForm(obj);
          };
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      input,textarea{margin:5px 5px 5px 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h3 id="main-heading">Receipt Information</h3>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <br /><input type="date" name="date" id="dt"/>
        <br /><input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" id="amt" />
        <br /><input type="text" name="vendor" placeholder="Vendor" id="vndr"/>
        <br /><textarea name="notes" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="NOTES" id="notes"></textarea>
        <br/>Receipt Image
        <br /><input type="file" name="receipt" id="img" />
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

global.gs

```
var receiptImageFolderId='your receipt image folder id';
var SSID='your spreadsheet id';
```

The Spreadsheet Looks Like this:

> > Note I changed image Id to image Url so that you can just click on the url to get a viewer to look at the image.  I think this is much cleaner than trying to put images of varying sizes into the spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: Hi Cooper! Thanks a lot for this code! It works like a charm ! I'll go on learning by styling the html and also add the mail sender app. I really appreciate the help! That's really not my job to work with code, I came to it by necessity and curiosity too and I am really grateful to receive such help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this is an acceptable answer then I'd appreciate it if you would check it off.  Thanks

Comment: Done! Vote recorded but apparently won't be displayed online because i'm a new user here. Thanks again!